# Why Can't the C++ Compiler Find Librealsense?`

Tags: c++, cmake

I am new to C and C++.

I have a program. It has the following include statements:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include <librealsense>
#include <librealsense2/rs.hpp>
```

As I have learnt, the C++ compiler looks for the deceleration of these files at a bunch of different locations. Using the command

```
`gcc -print-prog-name=cc1plus` -v
```

I found that one of those locations was /usr/local/include.
In that directory is a librealsense diretory, a librealsense2 directory and glfw directory. Great.

But for whatever reason when I try to make the file using cmake, it cannot find the librealsense directories. Why is this? It seems to be in the correct place.

An additional question is, do I have to mention it in the CMakeLists.txt file?

My CmakeLists.txt file is as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project (YES)

include_directories(${glfw_INCLUDE_DIRS} "${YES_SOURCE_DIR}/deps")

set(GLAD "${YES_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/glad/glad.h"
         "${YES_SOURCE_DIR}/deps/glad.c")

add_executable(yes main.cpp ${GLAD})

target_link_libraries(yes glfw)
target_link_libraries(yes librealsense)
target_link_libraries(yes librealsense2)
```

However I get an error for the last two lines:

```
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -llibrealsense
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -llibrealsense2
```

Does Cmake look in different locations? To try and rectify this I decided to use the following:

```
find_library(librealsense NAMES librealsense  PATHS /usr/local/include)
find_library(librealsense2 NAMES librealsense2  PATHS /usr/local/include)
```

But it's really hard to find a guide for the find_library command. From reading the documentation I know that if the libraries are found at that path they are stored in the first argument. But how do i link that to the actual program that i'm trying to create? I tried:

```
add_executable(yes main.cpp librealsense librealsense2 ${GLAD})
```

But it says that it can't find the librealsense source files. So that method is only for source files (?) not variables (?)

Apologies for all the questions, but if any expert could answer all of them i would really appreciate it :]

Comment: Usually `lib` is just a system prefix for all libraries, it is not a part of library name. Try `target_link_libraries(yes realsense)`. Note, that `/usr/local/include` contains *headers*, not a **libraries**. But linker searches the *library*. (`find_library` command looks for library too, so a hint `/usr/local/include` is useless for it).

Comment: oh okay, thank you very much sir. i will try your advice out tomorrow. do you know how i can find where the libraries are stored?

Comment: Common places for libraries are `/lib/`, `/lib64/`, `/usr/lib`, etc.